# Root CA Certificate in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have one issue for jmeter.

I have add HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder and click on start button than one popup open the give error message.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just click ok and it will work fine.It is not an error. It just a pop up to install temporary certificate for proxy recording

Comment: It will be more helpful for other searchers, if you are able, to paste the text of the error dialog instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: What hinted you for such nature (error) of the message I wonder...?

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to Mozilla Firefox
2. Click on setting and then search for certificates in the search box
3. Then click on view certificates
4. Then a screen of certificate manager will appear
5. Then select authorities tab and click on import button
6. Then go to apache jmeter folder open it and
7. Then open bin folder
8. Then select Apache Jmeter Temporary Root CA and click on ok button
9. Then it will show two certificates and again click on ok
10. Then your certificate will be attached with jmeter.

Comment: Such an answer would looks fine with a list. It would help separating different steps. If you have motivation, some screenshot would help

Comment: This helped me!

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue, it is information message that JMeter has generated a self-signed certificate, i.e. 2 new files in it's bin folder:

- ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt
- ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.usr

They're required in order to allow JMeter to decrypt HTTPS traffic while doing recording of protected websites. If you're recording SSL/TLS traffic (your site URL has `https` prefix) - you need to install the certificate in your browser so JMeter could record encrypted traffic.

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (was: HTTP Proxy Server )](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), especially first 2 chapters:

  - HTTPS recording and certificates
  - Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)

---

If you're recording insecure traffic (i.e. `http` protocol only) - you can completely ignore this message

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you, You can use following usermanual of jmeter proxy pdf.

[Jmeter_Proxy_Step_by_Step.pdf](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

I hope it will work for you!!